# position text on divi slider to bottom right

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, divi, divi-theme

How I can position title bottom right of slide?

There is slide css in advanced slide settings.

I've tried:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 8px;
right: 16px;
```

but then my slide dissapears..

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your code, you need to make your slide relative and it should work.

```html
.slide {position: relative}
```

Another solution would be to use flex display on your slide and your title.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```html
position: relative;
bottom: 10px;
right: 16px;
```